# Javascript ES6, React, and EMACS

Tags: javascript

So, I'm finding myself writing React a lot, and not finding myself happy doing so in EMACS. I've been resorting to Visual Studio Code, which is a fine editor but suffers seriously by not being EMACS.

There seem to be a whole bunch of bits and pieces around, but little coherence. What is needed to make EMACS play nicely with modern Javascript, Node, and frameworks like React?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, you will need just [`js2-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode) for ECMAScript in general, and [`rjsx-mode`](https://github.com/felipeochoa/rjsx-mode) (a mode which derives from `js2-mode`) for jsx editing. These will provide you with some real-time linting like an IDE, and if you need more you can use something like [`flycheck`](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/), and there are plenty of extensions that take advantage of the AST provided by `js2-mode`.

You might need to customize some settings for `js2-mode` which you can do easily with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you install Indium (https://indium.readthedocs.io/) to get a stepping debugger, REPL and object inspector. Tern, company-tern, and js2-mode, js2-refactor, xref-js2, eslintd-fix, gulp-task-runner and yasnippet are very useful too.